# How to trim space from a property of an object present in an array of object?

Tags: reactjs, arrays, javascript-objects

I have an array of objects with me:
[Array of objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePLde.png)

Now, I want to change the property name of an particular object(not the value). For ex:
My object has attribute `PRODUCT NAME:'BAJAJ Brahmi Amla Hair Oil 300 ml'` in my data.

Required result:
`PRODUCT_NAME:'BAJAJ Brahmi Amla Hair Oil 300 ml'`

So, how can I replace the space in my property to an '_'.

Language used: React.js

I tried this function but it's not working for my desired result:

```
const productList = () => {
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  let obj = data[i];
  console.log(obj);
  Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
    var replacedKey = key.trim().toUpperCase().replace(/\s\s+/g, "_");
    if (key !== replacedKey) {
      obj[replacedKey] = obj[key];
      delete obj[key];
    }
  });
 }
};
```

Can somebody explain why is this not working ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you please change `replace(/\s\s+/g, "_")` to `replace(" ", "_")` and then try, as you can see the below code

```
const productList = () => {
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  let obj = data[i];
  console.log(obj);
  Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
    var replacedKey = key.trim().toUpperCase().replace(" ", "_");
    if (key !== replacedKey) {
      obj[replacedKey] = obj[key];
      delete obj[key];
    }
  });
 }
};
```

```js
const string = "PRODUCT NAME"
console.log(string.trim().toUpperCase().replace(" ", "_"))
```